# What are the component class names?

Tags: one-hit-kill

One Hit Kill has four component classes. Green is Bio. Red is elemental. In the first expansion, black is Death and purple is Lore. **What are the names of the yellow and blue components?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the [web app](http://app.onehitkillgame.com/). It has a lot of very detailed info about the game, including the names of each component class:

[image]